# ELB and CloudFront: Can I keep some folders on CloudFront and others on EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I have a load balancer which balances some EC2 instances. The three major instances are:

- www.domain.com/blog – LAMP. This is on EC2 and I want to keep it there
- www.domain.com/forum – Lamp. This is on EC2 and I want to keep it there
- www.domain.com – Windows. Rest everything I can move to Cloudfront

Due to budgetary constraints I want to keep Blog and Forums on EC2.

Can I keep the load balancer (with my DNS provider) before the Cloudfront which will help me

- keep redirecting the forum and blog requests to EC2 instances and
- direct all other requests to Cloudfront

Load Balancer currently success directs users between various EC2 instances, some on linux and some on windows platform

Setup I need it:

Load Balancer Checks request type:

If the URL contains /forum direct them to EC2

If the URL contains /blog direct them to EC2

If the URL does not contain either direct them to Cloudfront

Forum is - Xenforo

Blog is Wordpress

Comment: I don't get the problem. Why don't you create `CloudFront`, which points to your `ELB` - and routing still exists on `ELB` level (`/forum` and `/blog` can go through CloudFront aswell)

Comment: Putting website + blog + forum on cloud front the cost is coming to be 12000 $ per month. Forum + blog have 80% of traffic. I just want to keep e-commerce website on cloud front to save cost.

Comment: How did you calculated this cost? If you have 12 thousands USD for `CloudFront` with 2x EC2 instances - then something is really wrong

Comment: The IT team calculated bandwidth requirement of website + blog + VB forum at 4 TB per month. Business want to migrate to Cloudfront but we cannot pay $12000 per month.
Hence I am trying to find a solve which removes forum and blog from website. Website we definitely want on Cloudfront, we can live without blog and forum on Cloudfront.

Comment: According to CloudFront pricing, price for 1GB transfer OUT is from $0.085 (EU/Canada/US) to $0.170 (India) for first **10TB**. Which means 0.170 * 4096GB = 696,32$ - and this doesn't include FreeTier in `CloudFront`. **Data transfers from EC2 to Amazon CloudFront cost nothing.** Even with [AWS Cost Calculator](https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html), data transfer out costs ~367$ in Ireland.

Comment: So I was wrong at the number is 4000 GB a day.  Our monthly volume would be around 120,000 GB.  Which means 0.170 * 120,000GB = $20,400.

We used this page to calculate costs:
https://calculator.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html.  Data transfer out is 4000 GB a day and Data transfer to Origin would be slightly less but 4000 GB is a good place to start.  Average object size would be 100kb.  IF the objects are smaller say 10kb.  The cost goes up to $24,000.

Comment: Those calculations still are invalid. And i think you're still missing something. **You still pay for data transfer OUT from EC2** - it's not free, even without `CloudFront`. `CloudFront` can just reduce this costs.

Comment: Can I pay you for consultation

Comment: I'm here to help for free, as you can see you should consider recalculation of this costs with someone who's familiar with AWS pricing, IT team without experience can misunderstood that pricing.